# Why do I get a 500 internal service error when doing an AJAX post in Django

Tags: ajax, django

I am trying to send data to my database without having to load a new page.  Here is my Javascript:

```
    function submit(){
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("POST", "/185post/", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.send("noun=bananas&userAnswer=textajaxNow");
}
```

That will be processed by the following function in views.py:

```
def _185post(request):
    joke =Joke185.objects.all().filter(noun=request.POST.dict()['noun'])
    _185Joke = Joke(text=request.POST.dict()['userAnswer'],source='improv')
    _185Joke.save()
    print (_185Joke)
    joke[0].joke.add(_185Joke)
    joke[0].answers += 1
    print (joke[0].answers)
    joke[0].save()
    print (joke[0].save())
```

As you can see there are several print statements there and they all return what I expect them to, so I'm not sure why I'm getting a 500 Internal Service Error

Comment: the method _185post does not return HttpResponse or something like HttpResponse

Comment: Add your traceback too, but I think add some response fix your issue, also don't start your func with _

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you return something, your issue will solve, but there are more code suggestion

1- Don't use _ for starting functions

2- use logger instead of print

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def _185post(request):
    joke =Joke185.objects.all().filter(noun=request.POST.dict()['noun'])
    _185Joke = Joke(text=request.POST.dict()['userAnswer'],source='improv')
    _185Joke.save()
    print (_185Joke)
    joke[0].joke.add(_185Joke)
    joke[0].answers += 1
    print (joke[0].answers)
    joke[0].save()
    print (joke[0].save())
    return JsonResponse(joke[0])
```

Comment: Thanks, thought it looks like I need safe=False

But I don't want to return anything anyways...